# How does one use daisuki properly?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

I know "daisuki" means "big like," but what if I said "I like (daisuki) smart people" in Japanese, instead of telling a single individual that "I like him"? Would I be implying that I love/am sexually attracted to smart people as a whole?

Comment: Uhhh...「大好き」doesn't mean "big like" and it doesn't imply anything sexual, though it can be used to express someone's love of something sexual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would be the general idea about 大好き as you would use love in English.

> 日本が大好き。 I love Japan.
>
> 東京が大好き。 I love Tokyo.
>
> お寿司が大好き。 I love sushi (in general).
>
> アイドルが大好き。 I love pop idols. (but surely you have specific ones in mind)